# Operation with normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

I am working on a problem on finite group theory, and would like asking a question on the correct operation of normal subgroup.

Suppose that $H$ is normal subgroup of $G$ and the factor group $G/H$ is abelian: $\forall a,b \in G$ and $aH, bH \in G/H$:

$$\begin{align}
aHbH &=    bHaH    \qquad \qquad &&(1)  \\
abH &=    baH    &&(2)  \\
ab(ba)^{−1} &\in H    &&(3a)  \\
ab(ba)^{−1} &=H  &&(3b)  \\
\langle ab(ba)^{−1} \rangle &=H  &&(3c)  \\
aba^{−1}b^{−1} &= H  &&(4)\\
[a, b] &= H &&(5)\\
G' &= H &&(6) \\
\end{align} $$

My question is: Which one is correct, the (3a), (3b) or (3c)? Regardless of which one, I would like you showing me how to get to my final goal, which is (6) $G' = H$. Please advise and thank you for your time.

Comment: (3a) is true. it follows from the definition of normal subgroup. but your goal, (6), is not true in general. it should be $G' \leq H.$

Comment: (3b) is not true: left side is an element and right side is a set.

Comment: @Krish : Thanks to Krish and Anurag. I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

part $3c$ is not true since that would imply that there is only one $H$ so that $G/H$ is abelian, and this is not true since in particular in an abelian group $G$, $H$ can be any of the subgroups of $G$.

part $3b$ is also not true since the left is an element and the right is a set (good job)

part $3a$ is true.We need $H$ to contain all of the commutators, to see this write $abH=baH\implies abH(baH)^{-1}=H\implies ab(ba)^{-1}H=H\implies ab(ba)^{-1}\in H$.

Part $5$ is not true since the thing in the left is an element. And finally part $6$ is not true since we can use the same counterexample as for part $3c$.

What is true and you should prove is that if $\frac{G}{H}$ is abelian then $H<G'$.(This should be simple since by $3a$ $H$ contains all the commutators and $G'$ is the subgroup generated by the commutators.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the third paragraph, where you wrote that $ab(ba)^{-1}H = H \Longrightarrow ab(ba)^{-1} \in H$? It looks intuitive but I am lost when explaining in words. Thanks, I have green-checked and up-voted yours.

Comment: basically you want for the left coset $ab(ba)^{-1}H$ to be $H$ . So every element of the form $ab(ba)^{-1}h$ with $h\in H$ is in $H$ . Since $e\in H$ we have $ab(ba)^{-1}e\in H$, so $ab(ba)^{-1} \in H$